# Is "what benefit are something to something" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

In the series Young Sheldon season 1 episode 13 at 1:16 the following is said:

> But what benefit are rules to a dead man?

I also checked the subtitles and indeed this is what he says.

Is it grammatically correct? Shouldn't it be something like

> But what **of** benefit are rules to a dead man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not already grammatically correct then it is certainly widely used and it will probably become accepted usage in a short time.

No, it shouldn't be what you suggest. That is ungrammatical. It could be:

> But **of** what benefit are rules to a dead man?

Including "of" is more formal but "of" is widely omitted in such constructions.